# Anyone can help me on this discord bot command error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm doing a discord bot, at first it's just an XP bot, the problem is related with the output on the server, when i write the command in the chat commands. When i do a mencion for me or for another users, the bot do not response, ithis the same thing if i mention he or not mention anyone

follow de code bellow

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.guild_messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"), intents=intents)

xp_channel_id = 1186457318850838539  # Altere para o ID real do canal
config_file = "config.json"

# Verifica se o arquivo JSON já existe e carrega os dados
if os.path.exists(config_file):
    with open(config_file, "r") as f:
    config = json.load(f)
else:
    config = {"XP": {}}

def save_config():
    with open(config_file, "w") as f:
    json.dump(config, f, indent=4)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot conectado como {bot.user.name}')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == xp_channel_id and not message.author.bot:
        user_id = str(message.author.id)
        config["XP"][user_id] = config["XP"].get(user_id, 0) + 1

    # Verifica se o usuário atingiu 5 mensagens para atribuir XP
    if config["XP"][user_id] % 5 == 0:
            config["XP"][user_id] += 5  # Adiciona um bônus de 5 XP a cada 5 mensagens

    save_config()

await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command(name='ShowXP')
async def show_xp(ctx, user: discord.User = None):
    user = user or ctx.author
    if user.bot:
        return  
    # Ignora comandos de outros bots

user_id = str(user.id)
xp = config["XP"].get(user_id, 0)
level = int(xp ** 0.5)
await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} está no nível {level} com {xp} de XP! Continue assim ')

# Executa o bot
bot.run("XXXXXXXXX")`
```

firstly I tried redo the permissions, and the results is the same
after I tried to remove the json in the code and nothing
what made me more nervous is that I added debug messages in the functions on_message and in show_xp and both returns the message, so i think this is not a problem in the funcions, I've been trying to fix this for literally 2 weeks

anyway, thanks for your attention

Comment: Enable the message content intent, so your bot can read messages. `intents.message_content = True`

Comment: I don't know if you pasted it right, but the indentation in your code is a little off. The `process_commands` line and the last 4 lines of the command should be indented by one.